# Display SVG image in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

As far as I can tell from the documentation, Crystal Reports does not support vector graphics.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or know of any workarounds?

I have svg content stored in a database, and would like to display the images in Crystal Report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal Reports DOES support vector graphics via the Windows Meta File format. Supposedly that includes both the .WMF and .EMF formats, but I have only every got .WMF to work. Don't recall what the issue was with .EMF. I usually have to fiddle with the positioning to get the placement of .WMF files right, but they are sharp and look nice. Crystal Reports does not support the SVG format.

You could convert your SVG to a .WMF. Most vector editing programs will do the conversion.